# Is it possible to call a function, process some of its conditionals, break out, call it again and have it pickup where it left off?

Tags: python, function

If I have:

```
def foo(x):

    if x == y:
        blah
    elif x == z:
        blah1
    if x == y:
        blah2
    elif x == a:
        blah3
    if x == y:
        blah
    elif x == y:
        blah4
    if x == b:
        blah5
    elif x == c:
        blah6
```

Can I break out at, say, the end of the third condition, do some other processing and then have this function start from where it left off when I call it again?

Comment: I've formatted your "code" for you, but it still makes no sense to me. All for the conditions are the same. What is the real problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I *think* you're looking for a generator function, but it's fairly unclear what you're talking about.

Comment: It is unclear what sort of problem you are trying to solve. Give us a practical code example from your program so we can see it in context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Wooble says, you can use a generator for this, at least if I'm understanding what you want.  I've seen it a few times in the wild, but pretty infrequently.

```
def foo(x):
    if x == 6:
        print 'six'
    elif x == 3:
        print 'three'
    yield
    if x > 4:
        print 'greater than four'
    else:
        print 'not greater than four'
    yield
```

can produce

```
>>> f = foo(6)
>>> f
<generator object foo at 0x1004b25a0>
>>> next(f)
six
>>> next(f)
greater than four
>>> next(f)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

There's probably a better way to do what you want to do, though.

Comment: I was just typing something similar to this.  [PEP 255](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0255/) can also provide context and background into generators as well.